# scroll to top inside a scrollable div angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

This question has been asked many times, but most of them were unanswered and some of the solutions I tried did not work out.

In my page (angularjs), only the left half of it scrollable, I have put it inside a div element. Now how do I implement scroll to top inside the scrollable div.

For the entire page, i was able to do it with the below code

```
/** scroll to top function */
$scope.scrollToTop = function($var) {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 'fast');
};
```

How do I modify it so only in the left part we can scroll to top

Comment: you can use id or class of div as a selector $('sample').animate({scrollTop:0},'fast');

Comment: worked like a charm thanks, dont know why I dint try that before... keep it as an answer so others will find it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do it like with class or id

```
$('sample').animate({
 scrollTop:0
},'fast');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate(
       {scrollTop: $('#your-element').position().top} , '600', function() { 
            return false; 
       }
);
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4wdfb6cu/

Comment: Try the fiddle provided